Prove that learning PRG image of a DL doesn't help compute that DL
I've got a neat construction that I think is secure in the standard model, though so far I've only proven so in the random oracle model. It's definitely not true in a generic sense, as I can construct pathological primitives that satisfy the formal definitions but result in an insecure construction. But I think it's secure with sane primitives. To that end, I wish to prove the following:
Let $g$ generate some group where the DL problem is intractable, let $G$ be the first 16 bytes of output from a PRG constructed using fixed-key AES128 + MMO transform; that is, $G(x):= \mathrm{AES128}_k(x) \oplus x$ for some publicly known $k$. I just want to show that distinguishing pairs of the form $(g^x, G(x'))$ from those of the form $(g^x, Y)$ is computationally hard under the DL assumption and the assumption that AES is an ideal permutation, where both $x$ and $Y$ are uniform random in their domain and where $x'=x\bmod{2^{128}}$.
(I'm not married to $g^x$; I just need an unconditionally binding commitment to a uniform random value ~128-bits of entropy in it. So if some other type of commitment is provably secure, I'm all ears!)

What is the construction you say you have already proved secure in the random oracle model?

The construction is nearly identical. The corresponding part of the security proof involves choosing 128-bit x uniformly and then using the RO to stretch it into a 256-bit x. So, using the RO as the commitment scheme and the fact that we're stretching 128-bit inputs to 256-bit outputs, we can argue that this is statistically collision-resistant, thus perfectly binding with high probability. I guess assuming an ideal cipher is approximately equivalent to assuming an RO and not much of an improvement.

This is all in the context of an interactive proof system, which is ultimately converted into a non-interactive argument system. In this case, the DL commitments can become Pedersen commitments, and the proofs are easy. So maybe it's best just to use an RO in the interactive version and merely conjecture that the standard model version is also secure and call it a day.

The guarantee of a PRG only holds for uniform input distribution. However, for an arbitrary group $g^x$ may leak all kinds of information on $x$, making its distribution distinguishable from uniform. Therefore you should not be able to prove your construction without making additional assumptions.

If G is a pseudorandom function then those distributions should be indistinguishable. I think the problem is that you are using the wrong primitive. As @Maeher says, the PRG guarantee is not strong enough here.

It seems reasonable that G would also a PRF here, although I'm not familiar with the MMO transform.

@Lev Since the key is fixed, it's definitely not a PRF.

Notice that the inputs to G are all (within negligible distance of) uniform -- this was most definitely on purpose, so I'm guessing you're worried about the fact that this same randomness is used in two places. That's what I'm hoping to prove is not problematic and why I know that the proof needs to be specific to the chosen primitives, not vice versa.

MMO is for building compression functions. So this is like a very simple hash function.
The idea of using AES+MMO this way was famously suggested by Bellare, Hoang, Keelveedhi and Rogaway in the context of speeding up Garbled Circuit evaluations (https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/426), but I'm using it like Wang, Yun, Goldwasser, Vaikuntanathan and Zaharia as a PRG for the construction of DPFs (https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/1148), which coincidentally is essentially just the MMR construction for a PRF from any length-doubling PRG with extra steps.

Ok, since this construction is just a (theoretically significant) stepping-stone to a construction that doesn't even require these things to be indistinguishable, I have decided to just do the only (new-)assumption-less I can think of: Choose $x$ at random, then use $(g^x, G(gl(x)))$ where $gl(x)$ is just a $\lambda$ parallel applications of $\lambda$ random Goldreich-Levin hard-core predicates.

@Maeher of course not. But can you consider not using a fixed, public key $k$?
